# How to do conditioning in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop for array $students where I am trying to compare a paramater $find that I get from a form to $students array's $key value -> if they match it checks if the student is enrolled (this works) and if not it should print "Not found" but it doesn't do anything.. I have tried a lots of things but nothing works, please help!

I translated this from finnish so there might be typo's but the problem is in the syntax..

```
      //values come from a file
      $students[$key] = array('key' => $key, 'name' => $name, 'occ' => $occ);

        foreach ($students as $value) {

            //This doesn't work - $find comes from a form
                        if ($value["key"] != $find) {
                        $phase= "Not found";
                        $enroll= "";
                       //echo "$phase $enroll";
                       continue;
                        }

            //This works
            elseif ($value["key"] == $find) {

                $phase= $value["name"] . "(" . $value["key"] . "):";

                    if ($value["occ"] == "1") { 
                    $enroll= " yes";
                    continue;
                    } 

                    elseif ($value["occ"] == "0") {
                    $enroll=  "no";
                    continue;
                    } 
            } 

            //It prints out for example "John(1234): yes"
            //But nothing if the studentnumber = key doesn't match.. 
            echo "$phase $enroll";


        }
```

Comment: You need to move that echo line outside the loop. And also, in your `elseif` condition, if a match is found, you need to stop the loop execution by `break`.

Comment: Any time you execute `continue`, this will not execute anything else in the loop and will move to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check `$value["key"]` twice

```
 $students[$key] = array('key' => $key, 'name' => $name, 'occ' => $occ);

foreach ( $students as $value ) {
    $phase= "Not found";
    $enroll= "";
    if ( $value["key"] == $find ) {
        $phase= $value["name"] . "(" . $value["key"] . "):";
        $enroll = ( $value["occ"] == "1" ) ? " yes" : "no";
    }
    echo "$phase $enroll";
}
```